# Memory reduction

Tags: python, memory, floating-point

I am not a programmer but am facing a programming problem. I need to reduce the memory consumption of a Python code. One option is to reduce the variable precision. In this regard:

1. Identify Floating points (as I think the data types are assigned on the fly)?
2. Python uses 64-bit or 32-bit floating points?
3. Any function to reduce floating precision or convert to int?

Kindly help me. These questions may be stupid, but I have very less knowledge of Programming.

Thanks...

Comment: If you have a highly numeric code, then you should be using Numpy.

Comment: If you posted some code, we could give you a much better solution. If you have a lot, just post a representation of what most of it looks like. (Keep it short!)

Comment: Hi, The code uses huge data and the processor is not able to handle the complexity. I am already using Numpy. Can you elaborate your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using `numpy` you can set the `dtype` field to the type that you want ([documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)). You'll get a little more flexibility there for typing, but in general you aren't going to get a lot of control over variable precision in Python.  You might also have some luck if you want to go through the structural overhead of using the static types from [Cython](http://cython.org/), though if you are new to programming that may not be the best route.

Beyond that, you haven't given us a lot to work with regarding your actual problem and why you feel that the variable precision is the best spot for optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Pure CPython (sans numpy, etc.) floats are implemented as C doubles.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-python1/

Yes, the types are associated with values, not variables.  You can check for something being a Python float with isinstance(something, float).

You could perhaps try objgraph to see what's using your memory.
http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/

There's also a possibility that you are leaking memory, or merely need a garbage collection.  And it could be that your machine just doesn't have much memory - sometimes it's cheaper to throw a little extra RAM, or even a little more swap space, at a constrained memory problem.

It's possible that using a low precision, alternative numeric representation would help - perhaps http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Simple%20Python%20Fixed-Point%20Module/0.6 ?.